# 3n+1 problem: $f^x(n) < n$ finitely many steps

Tags: collatz-conjecture

Consider the shortcut function:
$$f(n)=\begin{cases}(3n+1)/2\} & \text{if } (n\bmod 2)\equiv1 \\
\{n/2\} & \text{if } (n\bmod 2)\equiv0 \end{cases}$$

Define $f^x$ as the $x$'th iterate of $f$.

There is an initial number $n_0$ (i.e. a constant in the inequality equation) such that for all $n \in\mathbb{N}$ there is some $x$ such that $f^x(n) < n_0$. 
If someone confirmed/proved that this were true, would that mean that the sequence would never reach $\infty$, but might be open wether it would enter a non-trivial repeating cycle?

I.e. for all $n \in\mathbb{N}$ will there always exist some $x$ where $f^x$ is strictly less than $f^0$? I am just wondering if this have been proven. If so, is the proof simple? If my math-writings are wrong, please correct me. If someone proved it, would we rule out that it would enter infinity, or am my assumptions wrong?

**Illustration**

Set $n_0 = 27$. Start the iterate with $f(n_0)$.

We get: $27, 41, 62, 31, 47, 71, 107, 161, 242, 121, 182, 91, 137, 206, 103, 155, 233, 350, 175, 263, 395, 593, 890, 445, 668, 334, 167, 251, 377, 566, 283, 425, 638, 319, 479, 719, 1079, 1619, 2429, 3644, 1822, 911, 1367, 2051, 3077, 4616, 2308, 1154, 577, 866, 433, 650, 325, 488, 244, 122, 61, 92, 46, 23,...$

After $59$ steps we get number $23$ which is less than the initial number $27$.

So for $n_0=27$ there is some $x$ where $f^x < f^0$. In this case $f^{59} < 27$.

Comment: Since $(\mathbb{N},<)$ is well founded, your first statement can't hold : take any $n_0> 0$,   
you find $x_0$ such that $n_1 := f^{x_0}(n_0) <n$  
then you find $x_1$ such that $n_2 := f^{x_1}(n_1) < n_1$ etc
... and the sequence $(n_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an infinite decreasing sequence, which can't be.

Comment: @OlivierRoche Not sure I follow you. I switched out $n$ with $n_0$ now in the post. The right side of the inequality should be a constant, i.e. the initial number. I represented this as $n_0$ now. My math notation is not perfect. Ill make an example in the post to be more clear what I ask.

Comment: Any object you're referring to must be defined somewhere. For example,who is $n_0$? You need to restate this as "there is a number $n_0$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there is some $x$ such that $f^x(n) < n_0$".


What is $f^o$???

Comment: ok. ill try my best to define them.

Comment: Please edit the post if I am way out there...

Comment: No offense but statistically, if you're writing on Collatz on MSE, you're way out.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier No worries. Where else? I dont know any other forums to get feedback or write about this.

Comment: Is $n_0$ independent of the seed (the first input to the Collatz function)?

Comment: @DavidDiaz not really, it's the same number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not known if any Collatz sequences go to infinity. It is not known if there are any cycles apart from the trivial $1\to4\to2\to1$. It is possible that no Collatz sequence goes to infinity but that some non-trivial cycle exists anyway.

To prove Collatz, you need only prove your statement. That is, if all starting seeds return a Collatz sequence that is eventually smaller than the seed, you're done. No cycle could possibly exist. (Consider the Collatz sequence beginning at the minimum of the cycle.)

On the other hand, if you show that some fixed integer exists that is greater than some element of every Collatz sequence, then no Collatz sequence diverges but a cycle might exist.

---

To elaborate:

As you state, for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$, $f^x(1) \not < 1$. So the inequality does not hold for $n_0 = 1$. If it holds for $n_0 = 2$, we can be sure that the orbit starting at $2$ eventually goes to a number smaller than $2$: it must go to $1$. *(Note it cannot go to zero or a negative number; these numbers are not the odd parts of any positive number.)* If it holds for $n_0 = 3$, we can be sure that orbits starting at $3$ eventually go to $1$ or $2$ and all sequences that go to $1$ or $2$ go to $1$. Proceeding in this way, if the inequality holds for all $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ then all sequences go to $1$.

> Well if $1$ is part of a cycle, why can't some other cycle exist?

By way of contradiction, lets assume your inequality is true and that some cycle exists: $$a_0 \to a_1 \to \dots \to a_{100} \to a_0$$ This Collatz orbit must have a smallest element. Call it $a_0$. Then for all elements in this cycle $a_k, k\not= 0$, the orbit starting at $a_k$ goes to $a_0 < a_k$. But element $a_0$ is the minimum element of a cycle, and thus never reaches a smaller element. Therefore either your inequality is not true for all starting seeds or there cannot be a cycle.

Comment: Before I accept your answer, could you explain how other non-trivial cycles could not exist (if that statement is proved)? Because the trivial cycle $2\rightarrow1\rightarrow2\rightarrow1$... loops. The number $2$ accepts the inequality, but $1$ does not. Because if I start with initial number $1$ which is odd, will jump up to $2$, then back to $1$ again and loop. My reasoning is that there allready exists a cycle when the inequality holds, why wouldn't it hold if another cycle existed?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3377955/collatz-conjecture-heuristics-probabilities-methods/3419579#3419579 might be useful.